# Converting excel formulae to JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, math

I have this formula and it uses powers e.g. '10 to the power 30'

```
=B2*(B3/12) / (1-(1+(B3/12)) ^ -B6)
```

The problem is that I can't put `^` in JS/jQuery, I have to use `Math.pow()` as the equivalent.

I've tried quite a few different positions but I can't seem to get it correct, the brackets really confuse me. Which parts of the formula would I wrap the `.pow` within?

My attempt:  `=B2*(B3/12) / Math.pow(   (1-(1+(B3/12)) ,  -B6)  )`

**UPDATE:**
Please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tog5s6y0/3/)

Fiddle code:

```
var B2 = 500000; //£500,000
var B3 = 2.00; //2.00%
var B6 = 300; //Total number of payments

var original_formula =  'B2*(B3/12)/(1-(1+(B3/12))^-B6)';

var x = B2 * (B3 / 12) / Math.pow(1 - (1 + (B3 / 12)), -B6)

console.log(x);

//Expected/Excel result = 2,119.27
//Actual result  = 2.9884337938456618e-229 <- what's going on here?
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse excel formulas using JS or just port existing excel formulas into JS?

Comment: If you were able to provide some sample values for B2, B3, and B6, with expected (Excel) outcome, that would help someone replicate the issue and construct a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to just port it over and I've added some samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=B2*(B3/12) / (1-(1+(B3/12)) ^ -B6)
```

is the same as

```
=B2*B3/12 / ( 1 - (1+B3/12) ^ -B6 )
```

With this reduced number of parantheses it is perhaps easier to see that the javascript implementation should be

```
= B2*B3/12 / ( 1 - Math.pow(1+B3/12, -B6) )
```

---

You also need to translate `B3=2.00%` into `B3=2.00/100` or `B3=0.02`. Then the result is indeed `2119.2716932202998`

```js
var B2 = 500000; //£500,000
var B3 = 2.00; //2.00%
var B6 = 300; //Total number of payments

var original_formula =  'B2*(B3/12)/(1-(1+(B3/12))^-B6)';

B3 = B3/100 // 2.0% is 0.02 as number
var x = B2*B3/12 / (1 - Math.pow(1 + B3/12, -B6) )

var log = document.getElementById("log")
log.innerHTML += "x="+x;
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Even when converting the 2% into a decimal, yours is the only one that works, the others are outputting 0

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried this, but one problem is probably that you're wrapping the two arguments in `Math.pow()` with a set parentheses.

In your original formula, you wrap the base and exponent in parentheses to group them together:

```
(1 - (1 + (B3 / 12)) ^ -B6)
```

`Math.pow()` takes two arguments, the base, and the exponent:
`Math.pow(base, exponent)`

You can't use parentheses across two arguments in Javascript, and in fact you don't need to since the `pow()` function knows that the two arguments should be used together.

So instead of:

```
Math.pow((1 - (1 + (B3 / 12)), -B6))
```

I think that should be more like:

```
Math.pow(1 - (1 + (B3 / 12)), -B6)
```

Comment: Yep, beat me to it. Here's a corrected working version: https://jsfiddle.net/tog5s6y0/

Comment: Please see this fiddle, it's not working correctly still.. https://jsfiddle.net/tog5s6y0/3/